# ¿Como registrar datos pero verificar antes si están en la base de datos usando un controlador con Angular?

Tags: angular

$scope.New_Customer = function(customer, AddNewForm) {
        console.log(customer);

```
    var data_name = $routeParams.data_name;
    if (data_name == true) {
      $http.get('api/Book/' + data_name).success(function() {
        $scope.reset();
        $scope.activePath = $location.path('/NewCustomer');
      });
      $scope.mymensaje = "datos encontrado: " + data_name;
    }
    else {

      $http.post('api/New_Customer', customer).success(function() {
        $scope.reset();
        $scope.activePath = $location.path('/dashboard');
      });
      $scope.reset = function() {
        $scope.customer = angular.copy($scope.master);
      };
      $scope.reset();
      alert('datos agregados');
    }
  }
```

}
]),

Comment: Manuel, edita tu pregunta y da mas informacion de lo que quieres sino nadie te podra ayudar.

Comment: Es tan difícil de entender ...como lo explico: existen dos correos iguales??? Respuesta no Todos todos todos los sistemas tienen un registro y un inicio de sesión y dos (2) usuarios no pueden tener correos o nombre de usuario iguales....